# Is it possible to convert CXF, CMF, DXF file format to SHP file and/or PostGIS format?

Tags: cxf, postgis, shapefile, dxf

I am exploring possible ways to convert a file from a CXF, CMF, DXF format to SHP or PostGIS format.

I found this [plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dxf2postgis/files/dxf2postgis/) but I haven't tested yet.

It would be nice if we could share some experience and start a kind of brainstorming about this topic.

Comment: *"I found this plugin but I haven't tested yet."* .. well, you should try it first and come back here if you have questions. I don't wanna be rude, but SO is a Q&A website, not a brainstorming platform. Cheers

Comment: btw QGIS might do what you want: https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_dxf2shape_converter.html

Comment: Hi Jim, many thanks for your reply. I'm just interested in learning something new from someone more experienced than me. I am not even sure PostGIS will be the best tool for this job.

Comment: It all depends on your use case, but I can tell you something: If you need to execute spatial operations with your data within a relational database, I cannot think of a better choice than PostGIS.